# Python BS4 - NameError: name 'tagID' is not defined

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm new to python. I'm building an app to parse and clean MSWord generated HTML.
In the following code, I pass in content as a BS4 object and I'attempt to update a specific span tag with new attributes.

```
content = ' <html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
    <span style="background: #c0c0c0">Table 1</span>
    <span style="background: #c0c0c0">Figure 1</span>
    </body>
    </html>'

def clean_table_figure_id_tags(content):
    for element in content.findAll('span', style='background: #ccc0'):
        # inspect the existing tag a to determine table or figure
        if 'Table' in element.string:
            tagID = 'TableId'
        elif 'Figure' in element.string:
            tagID = 'FigureId'
        # tagID = content(elementString)
        newTag = Tag(builder=content.builder, name='span', attrs={'id': tagID, 'class': 'variable'})
        newTag.string = element.string
        element.replace_with(newTag)
    return content
```

However, I receive the following error: `NameError: name 'tagID' is not defined`
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You'll have to edit your question and add a simplified but representative version of `content` before anyone can help you.

Comment: see [ask] a question, and provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you are looking for something like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
content = """[your html above]"""
soup = bs(content,'lxml')

for elem in soup.select('span[style="background: #c0c0c0"]'):
    if "Table" in elem.text:
        elem.attrs['id'] = 'TableId'
    if "Figure" in elem.text:
        elem.attrs['id'] = 'FigureId'
print(soup.prettify())
```

Output:

```
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
  <span id="TableId" style="background: #c0c0c0">
   Table 1
  </span>
  <span id="FigureId" style="background: #c0c0c0">
   Figure 1
  </span>
 </body>
</html>
```